# Getting the correct output value in calculator for Sin, Cos & Tan

Tags: swift

I am learning Swift by using the Stanford ios10 course notes and I was checking the output of Cos and found it was not correct.
By research I found that the input value of the cos must be in Radians.
I have written a func to calculate the correct Natural Cosine.

```
func cosine(degrees: Double) -> Double {
    return cos(degrees*Double.pi/180)
}
```

When I tried modifying the following, to:

```
"cos" : Operation.unaryOperation(cosine(degrees)),
```

It said "use of unresolved identifier 'degrees'"

This is the var I was trying to modify:

```
private var operations: Dictionary<String,Operation> = [
    "π" : Operation.constant(Double.pi),
    "e" : Operation.constant(M_E),
    "√" : Operation.unaryOperation(sqrt),
    "cos" : Operation.unaryOperation(cos),
    "±" : Operation.unaryOperation({-$0}),
    "×" : Operation.binaryOperation({ $0 * $1}),
    "÷" : Operation.binaryOperation({ $0 / $1}),
    "+" : Operation.binaryOperation(){ $0 + $1},
    "−" : Operation.binaryOperation(){ $0 - $1},
    "=" : Operation.equals
]
```

As I am a beginner I'm not sure that I am doing it right!
Please help!

Comment: well, what is `"cos" : Operation.unaryOperation(cosine(degrees))` *supposed* to do?

Comment: Of course it said that. You are saying `"cos" : Operation.unaryOperation(cosine(degrees))`. Well, what _is_ `degrees`? Nothing!  There is no `degrees` anywhere in sight. It is indeed an unresolved identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the arguments you pass to the binary operators and the `-` unary operator. Pass the same argument to `cosine`.

```
"cos" : Operation.unaryOperation({cosine(degrees: $0)}),
```

Do the same for your `sqrt` function.

Comment: His `cosine` function has a labeled parameter. Your code won't compile.

Comment: @matt - Fixed now.

Comment: Or just `Operation.unaryOperation(cosine)`

Comment: The former worked '"cos" : Operation.unaryOperation({cosine(degrees: $0)}),'

Comment: @TonyHudson Do you mean the code in my answer worked? If so, please click the checkmark next to the answer to indicate that it solves your issue.